# Is it possible to use Newton's method on a function with an integral?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

So I have a root solving problem where I want to find x, but my equation is:
$$
0=1-p+c_2\int_0^Xt^{\alpha-1}e^{-t/2}dt
$$
where $0\le p\le1, c_2\ge2$, $1\le\alpha$. Is it possible to use Newton's method on equation containing an integral? If so, how would one calculate the derivative, or would the just use the standard derivative formula $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for h small?

Comment: Can't you just use the Foundamental Calculus Theorem  differentiating both sides?

Comment: I can't take the derivative of the integral because $t^{\alpha}-1e^{-t/2}$ requires integration by parts but $\alpha$ is some unknown constant so you can't integrate until $\alpha$ is known, which will be at run time.

Comment: If $F(x) = \int_0^x t^{\alpha-1}\operatorname{e}^{-t/2} \operatorname d t$, then $F'(x)= x^{\alpha-1}\operatorname{e}^{-x/2} $

Comment: that's embarrassing that I couldn't see that

Comment: Are there any proprierties on constants $\alpha$ and $c_2$?

Comment: @SewerKeeper, see updated question above, I forgot to change one of the $\alpha$ values to p

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\Gamma \left(\alpha ,\frac{x}{2}\right)-k \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\Gamma (\alpha )-\frac{ (\alpha -1)}{c \,2^{\alpha }}$$ with,as said in comments,
$$f'(x)=-2^{-\alpha } e^{-x/2} x^{\alpha -1}$$

The only problem would be to find a suitable $x_0$ to start iterations.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're pulling these equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$
f(x) = c_2 \int_0^x t^{\alpha -1} \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{t}{2}}\operatorname d t + 1 - p
$$

We note that $f$ is defined for $x \ge  0 $, moreover 
$$ f(0) = 1 -p \ge 0$$
If we differentiate, we obtain

$$
f'(x) = x^{\alpha-1}\operatorname{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}}\ge 0 \qquad \text{ for all $x\ge 0$ }
$$

Since $f' > 0 $, the function $f$ is in increasing.

Conclusion: the only possible zero is $x=0$, if $p=1$.

Comment: Ya I've just run into that, which means that I messed up deriving my original equation because I know for a fact that there has to be a solution.